# Rudin-Principles of Mathematical Analysis; pg. 2 [step (3) of a demonstration]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers

In this example, it's being demonstrated that for every $p$ ($p>0$), in $A$, ($A$ being the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2<2$, and for every $p$ in $B$ ($B$ being the set of all rational numbers $p$ such that $p^2>2$, there exists a rational $q$ in $A$ such that $q>p$, and a rational $q$ in $B$ such that $q<p$.

It then goes on to say we can do this by associating each $p$ with a number:
$$q=p-\frac{p^2-2}{p+2}$$

Why do we express $q$ in such a manner; how and why is this a good representation of $q$ as it relates to $p$?

Comment: That so defined $q$ satisfies the conditions above can be verified by calculation. The motivation behind this construction is to modify $p$ by a number smaller in magnitude than $p-\sqrt{2}$ and with the same sign as $p-\sqrt{2}$. You may as well change the denominator to $p+3$, $p+4$, etc.